# Clicking Android notification with extras to initialize app or update data: not handled when app was started by previous notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My app shows a notification when a push message for a chat message is received. When I click that message, I want to start the app (if it hasn't started yet) which should directly forward to the specific chat screen (so not the home screen). If the app is already present in that screen, it updates the shown messages (actually similar to WhatsApp).

Currently, this seems to work pretty well in most cases, except for this:

- Click a chat notification when the app is closed (the app is started correctly, in the chat screen I expect it to start in)
- Navigate away from that screen
- A new notification is received (even if this is a chat from a different person)
- Click this new notification
- The notification action isn't handled at all. The app is brought to the foreground, but nothing else happens.

Note: the notification click is always handled correctly when the app was initially launched in a normal way (so NOT through a notification click), no matter which notification I receive and how often I navigate to and from chat screens.

***Some info & code:***

My app has several activities, of which the most important are MainActivity, a LoginActivity and an InitializationActivity (the latter is the launcher and chooses which of the other 2 should be started). Here's the relevant **Manifest**  part:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".activity.InitializationActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity
     android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
 <activity
     android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

**InitializationActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    decideStartUpMode();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    // Just to be sure the intent from a notification is also saved through this method.
    // However, should not be required, because this activity is always destroyed before starting a new one.
    // Doesn't appear to be called in any case (decideStartUpMode is always called through onStart)
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    decideStartUpMode();
}

private void decideStartUpMode()
{
    if (!isUserLoggedIn())
    {
        startLoginActivity();
    }
    else
    {
        // Starts some API calls to collect the required user info.
        // When the data is collected we callback to this class and start the MainActivity.
        startInitialization();
    }
}

...

private void startMainActivity()
{
    Intent intentActivityMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intentActivityMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Collect (Pending)Intent from eg. notification - if present - and add this to the new activity
    Intent intentInitializationActivity = getIntent();
    intentActivityMain.setAction(intentInitializationActivity.getAction());
    intentActivityMain.setData(intentInitializationActivity.getData());
    Bundle extras = intentInitializationActivity.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    { // Extra's from notification
        intentActivityMain.putExtras(extras);
    }

    startActivity(intentActivityMain);
    finish();
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
// INTENT_HANDLER will handle the actions from clicked push notifications

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    INTENT_HANDLER.doIntentAction(getIntent(), this); // If activity is started through InitializationActivity
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
    INTENT_HANDLER.doIntentAction(newIntent, this); // If activity was already active
}
```

Finally the creation of the notification with launcher intent:

```
public void showChatNotification(Context context, ChatNotification chatNotificationData)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(CHAT_NOTIFICATION_DATA, chatNotificationData);

    PendingIntent onNotificationClickIntent = getAppLauncherIntent(context, CHAT_NOTIFICATION, notificationId, extras);
    String channelId = // ... also create channel if not exists ...
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), channelId);
    notification.setContentIntent(onNotificationClickIntent);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    // ... Set other notification data: title, message, etc...
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) 
           .notify(notificationId.id, notification.build());
}

private PendingIntent getAppLauncherIntent(Context context, String action, NotificationId notificationId, Bundle extras)
{
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    intent.setAction(action);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

In normal cases a click on a notification is always handled through the InitializationActivity (`onCreate` > `onStart` > `startInitialization` > `startMainActivity`) followed by the MainActivity (`onCreate` or `onHandleIntent`). However, the InitializationActivity is NOT called when I click on a notification AFTER I initially started the app through another notification (neither of the methods described above nor onHandleIntent).

Why is this going wrong in this specific situation, while all other notification clicks are handled correctly? Is my app initialized incorrectly through a notification with the `PendingIntent` - maybe due to the used flag - so it cannot handle new notifications anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by changing the manifest from

```
<activity
     android:name=".activity.InitializationActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

to

```
<activity
     android:name=".activity.InitializationActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

I don't completely understand why (and yes I did read the docs of both flags), so a clear explanation in the comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the app from a `Notification`, if the app isn't already running, Android will create a new task for the app and launch the `Activity` into that task. Android remembers the `Intent` that it used to start the task.
If, later, the user launches the app from a `Notification`, Android just brings the existing task to the foreground because the `Intent` used to launch the app matches the `Intent` that the task was originally launched with AND the `Intent` contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This is why you see this strange behaviour when the app is initially launched from a `Notification`.

To prevent this behaviour, you need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` to the `Intent` that you use in your `Notification`. This will prevent Android from remembering that the user launched the application using this `Intent`.

Comment: I added this line to the `getAppLauncherIntent` method: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)`, but it doesn't solve the problem (and I guess you don't mean the `PendingIntent` because it has no `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`). Additionally, I directly finish the InitializationActivity when starting the MainActivity, so the task shouldn't be present anymore anyway, right? Could you please clarify your answer if I understood incorrect?

Comment: You should use `intent.addFlags()` not `intent.setFlags()`. When you use `setFlags()` you are clearing other flags that have already been set. This is probably causing the problem.

Comment: Even if you finish `InitializationActivity` when starting `MainActivity`, Android remembers how the task was started. The task is still present, it now contains `MainActivity`. When you click the notification again, Android finds an existing task that was started with the same `Intent` and brings that task to the foreground.